# Show that there exists a line which intersects two lines and is perpendicular to both in $3$d

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, cross-product

> Show that there exists a line which intersects two lines and is perpendicular to both in $3$d.

I'm trying to consider parallel planes which contain the lines but am not getting very far in terms of a rigorous proof.

Comment: An equation of a plane can be established that contains the directional vectors of the given lines. Now thing normal! (No pun intended)

Comment: There is a fun proof of this statement which goes as follows: take two points from these two lines such that the distance between those 2 points is minimal, take a line trough those 2 points, it will be perpendicular to both lines. So it proves the line exists but doesn't compute it :D

Comment: so (r-a).b = 0 where a is a point on the line and b is the direction gives the general plane r which contains the line. where do we go from here?

Comment: funny because i don't think that proves it. We know that if such a line exists only once it will produce the minimal distance. How do we know that in the first place?

Comment: It requires knowing first that the nearest point on a line to a given point not on the line lies on the perpendicular through the latter (i.e., that distance to the line is measured along the perpendicular), but beyond that a simple symmetry argument suffices. Existence and uniqueness of that perpendicular line is a standard theorem of Euclidean geometry.